# Rerender child component after API returns data

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I have a `ParentComponent` that makes an API call. When the API call is complete, I'd like the `ChildComponent` that depends on an array of items from that API to rerender with those items.

I've seen a trick where you can do something like:

```html
<script>
  if(rerenderComponent) rendered = true;
</script>

{#key rendered}
  <ChildComponent {items} />
{/key}
```

Where I can force a rerender of that component. This seems like I'm trying to make svelte do something it doesn't want to do and I wonder if there's a better more "Svelete"ish way to do this?

Here's my code:

**App.svelte:**

```html
<script>
  import ParentComponent from './testing/ParentComponent.svelte'
</script>

<ParentComponent />
```

**ParentComponent.svelte:**

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
  import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.svelte'

  let items = []
  let value = ''

  onMount(async function () {
    console.log('ParentComponent onMount')
    await loadItems()
  })

  async function loadItems() {
    console.log('loadItems started:')
    const response = await getItemsFromApi()
    const data = await response
    items = data['items']
    console.log('loadItems completed:', { items })
  }

  function getItemsFromApi() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(
        resolve({
          items: [
            { text: 'Item 1', value: 'item_1' },
            { text: 'Item 2', value: 'item_2' },
            { text: 'Item 3', value: 'item_3' },
          ],
        }),
        Math.random() * 1000
      )
    })
  }
</script>

<ChildComponent label="ChildComponent w/o other text field:" {items} {value} />
```

**ChildComponent.svelte:**

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'

  export let label = ''
  // format: { text:, value: }
  export let items = []
  export let value = ''

  onMount(() => {
    console.log('ChildComponent onMount')
  })

  $: options = buildItems()

  function buildItems() {
    let tempItems = [{ text: 'Please select...', value: '' }, ...items]
    return tempItems
  }

  console.log('ChildComponent items:', { items })
</script>

<div>
  <div>{label}</div>
  <select>
    {#each options as option (Math.random())}
      <option value={option.value} selected={value === option.value}>{option.text}</option>
    {/each}
  </select>
</div>
```

This is the log output for when the code runs:

```
ChildComponent items: {items: Array(0)}
ChildComponent.svelte:15 ChildComponent onMount
ParentComponent.svelte:9 ParentComponent onMount
ParentComponent.svelte:14 loadItems started:
ParentComponent.svelte:18 loadItems completed: {items: Array(3)}
```

I'm expecting the `ChildComponent` to rerender because in the `loadItems` I set `items` which should trigger the `ParentComponent` to rerender.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reactive statement has no changing dependencies:

```js
$: options = buildItems()
```

This will only run once. Svelte will not check the function contents.

Just inline the function:

```js
$: options = [
  { text: 'Please select...', value: '' },
  ...items,
]
```

If you need multiple statements, you can also declare blocks or use an IIFE:

```js
let options = [];
$: {
  // [do stuff]

  options = stuff;
}
```

```js
$: options = (() => {
  // [do stuff]

  return stuff;
})()
```

Or declare the function reactively:

```js
$: options = buildItems()
$: buildItems = function() { ... }
```